# Live-server alternatives for node 6.10

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm-live-server

I need to use live-server for a project, as well as Node v6.10.0. From my understanding and trial-and-error, live-server is not compatible with this version of Node and I cannot use ng serve because AngularCLI is not compatible neither.

The Node version is a must, so although I have no issues with live-server using 8.17, I have to use v6.10.Can anyone help me with an alternative?

The error I get when trying to run the live-server is:

```
const wslToWindowsPath = async path => {
                           ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous>`
```